# The Uber API Is asking for Scopes but I cannot request full access or select the scopes

Tags: uber-api

When I'm trying to create token to use the API I do not have the required scopes and neither the options to request it

{"code":"unauthorized","message":"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: ride_request.estimate, profile"}

[Error when try to generate token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amyUk.png)

[Dashboard without the option for scopes selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EJRN.png)